# How can I check if I even have an argument to begin with in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, get

For a project in school, I need to print out of a database if an argument exists, and show the database if it doesn't. I can't figure out how to run the program without the argument.

In the database, I can grab what I need with SELECT workshop FROM people. However, I can't figure out how to grab it in my program.

```
 30 app.get("/api", async (req,res) => {
 31 
 32         
 33         try {
 34                 // if there is an argument
 35                 // else there isn't
 36                 
 37                 // find attendee
 38                 const template = "SELECT attendee FROM people WHERE workshop =$1";
 39                 const response = await pool.query(template, [req.query.workshop]);
 40                 console.log(response); 
 41                 
 42                 // prints all attendees, but has extra {}
 43                 if (response.rowCount!=0) {
 44                         res.json({attendees: response.rows});
 45                 }       
 46                 
 47                 // else if statement works right, write this in else      
 51                 // change this to print all workshops
 52                 // SELECT workshops FROM people;
 53                 else {
 54                         const temp = "SELECT workshop FROM people";
 55                         const resp = await pool.query(temp, [req.query]);
 56                         res.json({workshops: resp.rows});
 57                 }       
 58                 
 59                 
 60         } catch (err) {
 61                 console.error("whoops " + err);
 62                 res.json({status:"error"});
 63         }       
 64         
 65         
 66 });
```

error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

I don't understand how to fix this.

Comment: Remove the `[req.query]` from the second query, which doesn't use any `$1` parameter in its SQL.

Comment: So just `await pool.query("SELECT workshop FROM people")`